# stylesheet not found with asset in symfony

Tags: php, css, symfony, assets

I am currently learning `symfony (v. 4)` and trying to include a `.css` file in a template. However, I get this mistake:
`GET http://localhost:8000/css/app.css net:: ERR_ABORTED`

My template (`src/templates/index/tracking.html.twig`):

```
{% extends' base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="{{ asset ('css/app.css') }}" />
{% end block %}
...
```

My controller (`src/Controller/TrackingController.php`):

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use App\Entity\Time;

class TrackingController extends Controller {
    public function index () {
        return $this->render ('index/tracking.html.twig');
    }
}
```

My `CSS` file is located under `assets/css/app.css`. What am I doing wrong? How can I integrate the `CSS` file correctly?

Comment: you have `{{{` and a single `}`

Comment: copy & paste error... :D Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use Webpack-Encore, your css file should be in the "public/css" folder.

Comment: Yes, you put me on the right track and now it works. `webpack` was indeed not installed correctly. Thank you!

Comment: If you start learning, using webpack is not a priority. You can use old-fashioned css files first. Take time to familiarize yourself with the concepts of symfony beforehand. You can also download the "symfony-demo" application to be inspired by the code. I wish you a good learning experience, Symfony 4 is a great framework. PS: can you validate my answer please?